# Generate random unit vectors around circle

Tags: python, random, numpy, coordinate-system, vectorization

I'm trying to generate a bunch of uniformly distributed unit vectors around the unit circle. Here's my code, which is working, but unfortunately I have a for-loop. How do I get rid of this for-loop?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

def gen_rand_vecs(dims, number):
    vecs = np.random.uniform(low=-1, size=(number,dims))
    mags = np.sqrt((vecs*vecs).sum(axis=-1))
    # How to distribute the magnitude to the vectors
    for i in range(number):
        vecs[i,:] = vecs[i, :] / mags[i]
    return vecs

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
circle = np.array([np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)])

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(circle[0], circle[1])
rand_vecs = gen_rand_vecs(2, 100)
for e in rand_vecs:
    plt.plot([0,e[0]], [0,e[1]], 'r')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, you need to add a new dimension to the `ndarray`:

```
vecs /= mags[..., np.newaxis]
```

However

> uniformly distributed unit vectors around the unit circle

No it's not, at least not in \$\theta\$. You're generating uniformly distributed points on the unit n-sphere and modifying it to the unit circle; effectively reducing it to an angle. These angles will not be uniformly distributed, and this is easiest to show in 2D:

[image: The area of an angular slice is not invariant.]

Notice how the corner piece is *larger* than the side piece, despite both being \$30^{\circ}\$.

Instead, generate the original points with a normal distribution.

This is because the standard normal distribution has a probability density function of

$$
\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-x^2/2\right)
$$

so a 2D one has probability density

$$
\phi(x, y) = \phi(x) \phi(y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-(x^2 + y^2)/2\right)
$$

which can be expressed solely in terms of the distance from the origin, \$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\$:

$$
\phi(r) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-r^2/2\right)
$$

This formula applies for any number of dimensions (including \$1\$). This means that the distribution is independent of rotation (in any axis) and thus *must* be evenly distributed along the surface of an n-sphere.

Thanks to Michael Hardy for [that explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162081/141335).

This is as simple as using instead

```
np.random.normal(size=(number,dims))
```

Generating `mags` can also be just

```
np.linalg.norm(vecs, axis=-1)
```

A few minor changes then gets one to

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gen_rand_vecs(dims, number):
    vecs = np.random.normal(size=(number,dims))
    mags = np.linalg.norm(vecs, axis=-1)

    return vecs / mags[..., np.newaxis]

def main():
    fig = plt.figure()

    for e in gen_rand_vecs(2, 1000):
        plt.plot([0, e[0]], [0, e[1]], 'r')

    plt.show()

main()
```

The plotting is quite painful, so here's a cleaner, faster version ([credit HYRY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21357666/1763356)):

```
import numpy
from numpy import linalg, newaxis, random
from matplotlib import collections, pyplot

def gen_rand_vecs(dims, number):
    vecs = random.normal(size=(number,dims))
    mags = linalg.norm(vecs, axis=-1)

    return vecs / mags[..., newaxis]

def main():
    ends = gen_rand_vecs(2, 1000)

    # Add 0 vector to start
    vectors = numpy.insert(ends[:, newaxis], 0, 0, axis=1)

    figure, axis = pyplot.subplots()
    axis.add_collection(collections.LineCollection(vectors))
    axis.axis((-1, 1, -1, 1))

    pyplot.show()

main()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to do this for the unit *circle*, you can use `numpy.random.uniform` to choose the angle \$\theta\$ defining the unit vector.

If you want to deal with the more general case of the \$n\$-sphere, there is a method mentioned on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Generating_random_points).

> To generate uniformly distributed random points on the \$(n − 1)\$-sphere (i.e., the surface of the \$n\$-ball), Marsaglia (1972)
>   gives the following algorithm.
>
> Generate an \$n\$-dimensional vector of normal deviates (it suffices
>   to use \$N(0, 1)\$, although in fact the choice of the variance is
>   arbitrary), \$\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\$.
>
> Now calculate the "radius" of this point,
>   \$r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}\$.
>
> The vector \$\frac{1}{r} \mathbf{x}\$ is uniformly distributed over the
>   surface of the unit n-ball.

My attempt at translating that into Python would be

```
def get_rand_vec(dims):
    x = np.random.standard_normal(dims)
    r = np.sqrt((x*x).sum())
    return x / r


def gen_rand_vecs(dims, number):
    return [get_rand_vec(dims) for _ in xrange(number)]
```

---

@Veedrac's answer alerted me to the existence of `np.linalg.norm`, which gives us

```
def get_rand_vec(dims):
    x = np.random.standard_normal(dims)
    return x / np.linalg.norm(x)
```

Or

```
def gen_rand_vecs(dims, number):
    return map(lambda x: x / np.linalg.norm(x),
               [np.random.standard_normal(dims) for _ in xrange(number)])
```